# How to implement scrolling on the receiver page using iframe

Tags: chromecast

I have a receiver page which receives an url an it is used in an iframe.

I want from my android app have controls to make scrolling on that iframe, is it posible?

I am able to send messages from my android app to the receiver page without problem, but can't make scrolling.

I received the message,

"Blocked a frame with origin "receiver url" from accessing a frame with origin "iframe url". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

I know this is related with same origin policy, but how chromecast extension for chrome works? because I see it works well there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chromecast extension generates a video stream of the content in the Chrome tab. The scrolling is happening in the sender not the receiver.

Also, doing scrolling on the receiver would likely be a bad user experience for the Chromecast device. That kind of interaction is best suited for the sender device. The ChromeCast UI is best suited for fullscreen experiences that don't require scrolling.